# Visual Studio 2010 causing computer to lock up

Tags: visual-studio

When running the debugger about 50% of the time, Visual Studio 2010 freezes and also locks up my entire machine.  I can't even get to Task Manager.  Nothing works except my mouse will still move.  The only way to recover is to hard boot the machine which takes about 15 minutes each time.  I don't have anything else running on my machine at the time except VS, IE 8 (sometimes) and Outlook.

I am running Windows XP on a Lenovo T400 with 3G RAM

Has anyone seen this behavior?  If so, how did you fix it?

Thanks,

Rhonda

Comment: Oh and here is another weird behavior I run into occasionally on the same machine.  When I lock my machine to step away for a few minutes, Visual Studio shuts down.  If I have multiple instances of VS open, they are all closed when I come back and unlock my machine.

Comment: Turns out once I disabled the anti-virus software, problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what language your app is but I have run into this with our C++/CLI application on occasion. To avoid it, I changed the Project properties / Debugger and specify "Native" or "Managed" explicitly for the debugger type. The default of "Auto" can get confused.

Also, if you use Application Verifier from Microsoft, I have had VS hang while AV was configured to verify our .exe. To avoid this, we have to launch the app under the debugger as "Native".

Comment: It's an ASP.net application in C#.